# kTorrent cannot create directory

Tags: 22.04, directory, ktorrent

Ubuntu 22.04.2 and actual kTorrent coming with this release
Suddenly kTorrent has issue
***"cannot create directory $HOME/snap/ktorrent/18/.local/share/ktorrent/tor*/"***
(where $HOME is path to users home and * is a index number)
When it reports tor0, and i manuallz create tor0, in the next run it will report issues creating tor1, and so on.
Any ideas how to drill down and solve this issue?
Until it showed up, no updates were installed nor changes were done to the system.